# DoCmd.RunSQL in access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the below in a private sub but I don't know why I can't get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Me.FirstRecordL and Me.LastRecordL are a label in the same form where the command button is executing the sql. If I run the following it works: (but it deletes the whole table. i just want to delete the range of records between Me.FirstRecordL and Me.LastRecordL)

```
Private Sub RunSQL_Click()
DoCmd.RunSQL ("delete * from CTRTable")
End Sub
```

so, I am guessing the issue is with the " ' " and the &, they are killing me. I have tried multiple combinations but with no luck.

```
Private Sub RunSQL_Click()
DoCmd.RunSQL ("delete * from CTRTable where '[ctr #] >= & Me.FirstRecordL'" & "'[CTR #] <= & Me.LastRecordL'")
End Sub
```

I have tried in multiple forums but with no luck. I will love if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Are FirstRecordL and LastRecordL actually textboxes, not labels?

Comment: Look at how you are constructing your string, and work out why the command would not execute correctly.  If you can't work that out by looking at the code, then just output that concatenated string to a message box, read it, and then you should be able work out why the command will be failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation is messed up. Keep in mind all literal text goes between quotes and variables are concatenated outside quotes.

Also missing AND operator.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE FROM CTRTable " & _
              "WHERE [ctr #] >='" & Me.FirstRecordL & "' AND [CTR #] <='" & Me.LastRecordL & "'")
```

or

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE FROM CTRTable " & _
              "WHERE [ctr #] BETWEEN '" & Me.FirstRecordL & "' AND '" & Me.LastRecordL & "'")
```

To avoid popup warnings:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL ...
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Or use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM CTRTable " & _
              "WHERE [ctr #] BETWEEN '" & Me.FirstRecordL & "' AND '" & Me.LastRecordL & "'"
```

If [ctr #] is a number field, don't use apostrophe delimiters.

Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Better would be **CtrNum**.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your prompt response. i still get the run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method. what could be happening?

Comment: also, [ctr #] is a number. then which apostrophe should i remove the single ones ' or the double ones "?

Comment: The single ones are apostrophes, the doubles are quotes.

Comment: i still get the run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method. what could be happening?

Comment: The SQL works for me. FirstRecordL and LastRecordL are textboxes? I asked in other comment about them and you haven't answered. Your narrative said they are labels and that makes no sense.

Comment: sorry, i did not see the comment on top. yes, they are unbound text boxes on a form only to enter the range and the command button is in there.

Comment: Then this should work. Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.